# Running mysql scripts from windows task scheduler / "<" in windows task scheduler

Tags: mysql, windows, scheduled-tasks

I try to execute an sql script with the windows 7 task scheduler:

```
mysql.exe -uUser -pPass -DmyDB < script.sql
```

So in the task scheduler my script is

```
"C:\full\path\mysql.exe"
```

and the parameters are

```
"-uUser -pPass -DmyDB < "C:\full\path\script.sql"
```

The task is executed, but the parameters seems to be ignored. When I remove the '< "C:\full\path\script.sql"' pipe from the parameters, I end with the mysql command line. Is there any way work with "<" in windows task scheduler or any other workaround?

Comment: hello ACNB, I am stuck with the same problem with task scheduler. Did you found any solution of this problem? I yes, can you share me please.